# PHP Undefined error , trying to do email code

Tags: php, email, line

I tried to do email code, but I have error that I can't solve. Here is my code.

error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in line 5
```

code:

```
<?php
$Datacomment = 'data.txt';
$Key = '[@]';
$Key2 = '/n';

if($_POST['action'] == 'postcomment'){
   $Name    = str_replace(array($Key,$Key2),'',$_POST['name']);
   $Comment = str_replace(array($Key,$Key2),'',$_POST['content']); 
   $Comment = $Name.$Key.$Comment.$Key2; 


   $Modwrite = 'a';
   if(!file_exists($Datacomment)){
      $Modwrite = 'w';
   }
   $File = fopen($Datacomment,$Modwrite);
   fwrite($File,$Comment);
   fclose($File);

   header("Location: index.php"); /*replace comment.php by your homepage*/

}

/*load coment*/

if(!file_exists($Datacomment)){
   $Showcomment = '<div class="showcomment">No comment</div>';
}
else{
   $Cm = file_get_contents($Datacomment);
   $Array = explode($Key2,$Cm);
   $Total = count($Array) -1;
   $Showcomment = '<h3 style="margin-left:1%;">'.$Total.' comments</h3>';
   for($i = $Total-1;$i >= 0;$i--){
      $Arraycm  = explode($Key,$Array[$i]);
      $Name = $Arraycm[0];
      $Comment = $Arraycm[1];
      $Showcomment .= '<div class="showcomment"><h4>'.$Name.'</h4>'.$Comment.'</div>';
   }

}
?>

<style type="text/css">
   .showcomment { width:96%; float:left; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:1%; margin:0 0 10px 1%; color:#333;}
   .showcomment h4 { color:#03C; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
   .comment {width:400px; height:100px; outline:none;}
   .name { width:400px;outline:none}
</style>
<form style="margin-left:1%;"  action="comment.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="postcomment" />
    <h3>Enter your name :</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="name" />
    <h3>Eenter comment :</h3>
    <textarea name="content" class="comment"></textarea>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND COMMENT" />
    </p>
</form>

<?php echo $Showcomment;?>
```

Comment: how is the code you posted related to email? I see nothing of the kind.

Comment: The error message says you exactly, what is wrong. Maybe have a look at `isset()`.

Comment: Try `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['action'] == 'postcomment') ){...}` while changing `action="comment.php"` to `action=""` since you're running your entire code inside the same page.

Comment: You may also want to change `$Key2 = '/n';` to `$Key2 = '\n';` since you're most likely looking for a line break.

Comment: its not working guys :(

Comment: It's hard to say what you want to achieve with your code. You will need to tell us more. See what the answer does that's been given below, if it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first time you enter a comment.php validate

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'postcomment'){
```

when press submit send the parameter "action"